# Do I really need to wait a month before applying primer to plaster?

Tags: plaster, primer, spackling-paste

I've recently removed wallpaper and now I've gone through and plastered over some bad spots on the wall. I've already sanded it down and it's ready for primer. However, when reading the instructions on the primer, it says new plaster must age for 30 days before priming.  Do I really need to wait 30 days if I've just patched a few places up? What's the reason for waiting? Here's what I'm using in case it helps:

- Ace Vinyl Spackling
- Premium Royal Latex Primer

Comment: 30 days?  Is it possible that they're talking about the cure time for "real" plaster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for waiting is to ensure that the plaster dries completely. If you paint over damp plaster the moisture has to still come out - through the paint causing it to bubble and come away. You will end up having to repaint at the very least.

If you have only patched the wall then you should be able to prime and paint it sooner as there is less area to dry.

However, I would leave it as long as possible before painting, just to be sure.